# If $f$ is a linear function, then $f(5)+f(1)=f(3)+f(3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Suppose $f$ is a function where $f(x) = kx + m $

Quantity I: $f(5) + f(1)$
Quantity II:    $f(3) + f(3)$

The answer is that quantity 1 = quantity 2. But how do we prove this? Or is the answer sheet wrong?

Answer (score 2):

f(5) = 5k + m

f(1) = k + m

f(3) = 3k + m

Quantity 1 = f(5) + f(1)

Quantity 2 = f(3) + f(3)

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes thanks may the Lord be with you

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(x)+f(y)=k(x+y)+2m$ and so depends only on the value of $x+y$, not on the individual values of $x$ and $y$. Now apply this to $5+1=3+3$.

Answer (score 0):

As it's a linear function, it has a constant slope.

Slope between $x = 3$ and $x = 5$ is $\frac{f(5) - f(3)}{5-3} = \frac 12(f(5) - f(3))$

Slope between $x = 1$ and $x = 3$ is $\frac{f(3) - f(1)}{3-1} = \frac 12(f(3) - f(1))$

Those slopes are equal, so...